# Configuration on Ionic Framework?

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, ionic-framework

I have recently wanted to a create mobile apps so I decided to use a Mobile App framework that allows the use of web technology.

I decided to install Ionic and it went pretty well, until I hit the 'Configuration' section of its installation documentation.
https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html#configuration

It says that I have to do something related to 'src/app/app.module.ts' but I can't find that file anywhere, I have installed Angular and Zone using `npm install` but I still can't find this file.

Can anyone help me out finding out where this file is, or how I even get to it?

Currently, this is my project root folder structure:

I have a folder called node_modules, then I have 3 json files: .io-config.json, ionic.config.jon and package.json.